# Getting data type of each column from PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis

I need to get the column data types of all columns in a table, including the geometry types. What I wanted to know is if there is a function or SQL that gives something like this:

```
column_name | data_type
------------+--------------
gid         | integer
descr       | character varying(32)
class       | character varying(10)
area        | double precision
geom        | geometry(Polygon,3763)
```

From a few answers on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146705/select-datatype-of-the-field-in-postgres) and [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89200/how-to-get-the-geometry-type-of-an-empty-postgis-table) I know that I can get some of the information with the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
    g.column_name,
    g.data_type,
    g.character_maximum_length,
    g.udt_name,
    f.type,
    f.srid
FROM 
     information_schema.columns as g JOIN
     geometry_columns AS f 
         ON (g.table_schema = f.f_table_schema and g.table_name = f.f_table_name )
WHERE
    table_schema = 'my_schema_name' and
    table_name = 'my_table_name'
```

Result:

```
column_name | data_type         | character_maximum_length | udt_name | type    | srid
------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+------
gid         | integer           |                          |          |         |
descr       | character varying | 32                       |          |         |
class       | character varying | 10                       |          |         |
area        | double precision  |                          |
geom        | USER-DEFINED      |                          | geometry | Polygon | 3763
```

But, is there a proper more practical way to retrieve the information in the format I need? Or must I enter the "world" of `CASE WHEN` structures and string concatenation to gather all column attributes in one single column in that format?

My fear is if a non expected data type surprises me by needing other attribute from the information_schema.columns table. I.e, in the example table before, I did not used any `numeric (15,2)` data type, that would need to use another attributes (numeric_precision and numeric_scale) to be parsed by a CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The theory yes, though you could find it very complex indeed.

- Every table (select * from pg_class) has columns.
- Every column (select * from pg_attribute) optionally has a "typmod" number.
- For types with typmod (select * from pg_type) there will be a "typmodout" function.
- Running the typmod out function on a typmod number will return a string that can be concatenated with the type name to form the kind of user-readable signature you're used to (select 'numeric' || numerictypmodout(786441)) (select geography_typmod_out(1107460))

But, hey, psql generates the strings you want, if we look at what SQL it generates, maybe the answer is in there.

Sure enough, there is a magic function that takes a typeid and typmod and returns the magic string.

```
select a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) from pg_attribute a where attname = 'geog';
```

With a join to pg_class you should be able to get this info per-table.

Comment: I don't get any results for `where attname = 'geog'` but `= 'geom'` does work. This gives me good results for MultiPolygon, Point and MultiPoint values but I don't see anything for Line or MultiLine types. Are those considered polygons?

Answer (score 8):

With [Paul Ramsey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/457/paul-ramsey) help I made it this way:

```
SELECT a.attname as column_name, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM pg_attribute a
JOIN pg_class b ON (a.attrelid = b.relfilenode)
WHERE b.relname = 'my_table_name' and a.attstattarget = -1;
```

**UPDATE**

Meanwhile I have created a function to ask for a certain column data type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "vsr_get_data_type"(_t regclass, _c text)
  RETURNS text AS
$body$
DECLARE
    _schema text;
    _table text;
    data_type text;
BEGIN
-- Prepare names to use in index and trigger names
IF _t::text LIKE '%.%' THEN
    _schema := regexp_replace (split_part(_t::text, '.', 1),'"','','g');
    _table := regexp_replace (split_part(_t::text, '.', 2),'"','','g');
    ELSE
        _schema := 'public';
        _table := regexp_replace(_t::text,'"','','g');
    END IF;

    data_type := 
    (
        SELECT format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)
        FROM pg_attribute a 
        JOIN pg_class b ON (a.attrelid = b.oid)
        JOIN pg_namespace c ON (c.oid = b.relnamespace)
        WHERE
            b.relname = _table AND
            c.nspname = _schema AND
            a.attname = _c
     );

    RETURN data_type;
END
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The usage is:

```
SELECT vsr_get_data_type('schema_name.table_name','column_name')
```

Answer (score 7):

It can be get using a simple SQL query.

`SELECT * from information_schema.columns where table_name='mytablename'`

Comment: This works great! And here's a tip: The output can be kind of long, so you may want to enable the expanded display on your console: `\pset pager` to turn off the page, then `\x` to enable the expanded display.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to check geometry type you can check 'udt_name' in 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' and use it!:

`select column_name,udt_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name =g`