# Get the geometry type of an empty ArcSDE feature class

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I'm trying to use raw SQL to get the geometry type (e.g. `POINT`, `LINESTRING`, `POLYGON`) of an Oracle ArcSDE feature class using the `ST_Geometry` spatial type. If I run

`SELECT SDE.ST_GeometryType(SHAPE) FROM STREETS`

and the table is empty, I get zero results, even though I specified that it's a line layer at the time of creation. I've run into the same thing in PostGIS but there's a [workaround](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89200/how-to-get-the-geometry-type-of-an-empty-postgis-table) to still find the geometry type. Is there an equivalent for Esri `ST_Geometry`?

**EDIT**: The feature class was created interactively in ArcCatalog and will be populated using SQL statements, i.e. `INSERT INTO STREETS (SHAPE) VALUES (SDE.ST_Geometry('LINESTRING (...)', 4326))`.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify the mechanism for geometry creation.  Tables created by ArcGIS register the allowed types in a bitmask integer column in sde.layers, but SQL creation doesn't make such distinctions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Vince, I've added some details to the bottom.

Comment: Did you look into the Geometry_type column of the SDE Geometry_Columns table?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall mine just says `ST_GEOMETRY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sde.ST_GEOMETRY` type itself is typeless (it doesn't care if multiple topology classes exist).  However, ArcGIS for Desktop and Server **do** care, and won't permit multiple topology classes.

When geometry is created by PostGIS in PostgreSQL, the topology class is registered via an explicit `AddGeometryColumn` request.  `sde.ST_GEOMETRY` does not have an analogous method, but registration with the geodatabase does populate the `sde.LAYERS` table (and `sde.ST_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS`, though it's of no use for this purpose).  Of course, when you use ArcObjects (through Desktop, Pro, Server, or ArcPy) to create a feature class with `sde.ST_GEOMETRY` geometry storage, this population is automatically performed.

The permitted entity types are stored in the `EFLAGS` column in `sde.LAYERS` masked in with the following bit positions:

```
    NIL           -> 2^0    (1)
    POINT         -> 2^1    (2)
    LINE          -> 2^2    (4)
    SIMPLELINE    -> 2^3    (8)
    POLYGON       -> 2^4    (16)
    MULTIPART     -> 2^18   (262144)
```

Notes:

1. `sde.ST_GEOMETRY` distinguishes between Line ("spaghetti") and SimpleLine (the formal non-self-intersecting line), though most "line" features are defined to support either (bitwise AND)
2. Multi-part is just an attribute of Point, Line, SimpleLine and Polygon layers, not a list of separate types as in some other implementations

Therefore, it is only possible to determine the range of supported types in `sde.ST_GEOMETRY` if the table has been registered, at which point you can use the `sde.LAYERS.EFLAGS` mask with bitwise operators to determine which geometry flavors are supported.  Oracle itself has an idiosyncratic way of accessing bitwise operators, but the following example shows detection of the type of four tables (note that most layers are permitted NIL geometry)

```
SELECT  table_name,
        bitand(eflags,1) n,
        bitand(eflags,2) p,
        bitand(eflags,4) s,
        bitand(eflags,8) l,
        bitand(eflags,16) a,
        bitand(eflags,262144) "+"
FROM    sde.LAYERS
/


TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         N          P          S          L          A          +
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
EX_POINT
         1          2          0          0          0          0

EX_LINE
         1          0          4          8          0     262144

EX_POLYGON
         1          0          0          0         16     262144

EX_MULTIPOINT
         1          2          0          0          0     262144
```

There are other bit values masked in there as well, so it is best practice to avoid doing any sort of update on the `EFLAGS` value.

If you use a naming scheme that embeds topology class into the table name (e.g., "political_level0_a", and "water_250k_l"), you could simplify your processing significantly.